# ext.net 2.0 - get custom attributes of a tree node

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ext.net

I'm using ext.net with asp.net, I'm generating a tree using server side code:

```
    Ext.Net.Node rootNode = new Ext.Net.Node();
    rootNode.Text = "Home";
    rootNode.CustomAttributes.Add(new ConfigItem("absoluteNodeUrl", "'" + someValue+ "'", ParameterMode.Value));
```

I'm trying to get the **absoluteNodeUrl** attribute like that from client side javascript when a tree node is clicked:

```
    x=node.attributes['absoluteNodeUrl']
```

but I'm always getting the value of **undefiend** although this code worked with me before in version 1.3 of ext.net.

how can I modify the client side script to get the custom attribute?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom attribute name must be presented in store's Model as ModelField (or inside Fields collection of TreePanel)

Please see the following post
http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?19717-Raw-property-is-null-when-adding-a-node

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just call:

```
var x = node.absoluteNodeUrl;

// or...

var x = node['absoluteNodeUrl'];
```

Either should return the `absoluteNodeUrl` value.

I am making the assumption that the `node` variable in your sample is a valid instance of the actual root node.

Comment: unfortunaltley it didn't work, what I'm doing is adding a listener to BeforeLoad event. when a node is passed in operation parameter attribute, I couldn't get custom attribute so far using your suggested way, all I could get is getId() of node